# I have custom data which is return from stored procedure so I need to add those data into list<> and return in asp.net core web api c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Here is my code example:

```
 using (IDbConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constants.DefaultConnectionString))
 {
      if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
          con.Open();

      DynamicParameters parameter = new DynamicParameters();
      parameter.Add("@StandardObjectName", StandardObject);
      parameter.Add("@UserID", UserID);

      var AccountRecord = await con.QueryAsync<GetCustomDataForStandardObject>(
           StoredProcedure.GetCustomobjectDataForStandardObject, parameter, 
           commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

      var mapResult = Common.AutoMapper.MapListData<GetCustomDataForStandardObject, 
           GetStandardBYName>(AccountRecord.ToList());

      List<string> CustomData = new List<string>();
      GetCustomObjectLinkData Data = null;

      // DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      // LeadRecord.ToList();

      for (int a = 0; a < mapResult.Count; a++)
      {
           int customobjectid = 0;
           customobjectid = mapResult[a].CustomObjectID;
           DynamicParameters pa = new DynamicParameters();
           pa.Add("@CustomObjectSchemaId", customobjectid);
           var rowAffected = await con.QueryAsync(StoredProcedure.GetCustomObjectData, 
               pa, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
           rowAffected.ToList();
      }
}
```

I have multiple data rows for multiple customobjectid and I need to add those data into an array or list. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: FYI, `.ToList()` returns the collection as a new list. I see you call this method but don't do anything with the return value, so it's not doing anything. If you want `rowAffected` to be a list, then you would do: `var rowAffected = await con.QueryAsync(argsHere).ToList();`

Comment: Also, `rowAffected` is declared inside the `for` loop, so it's scope is limited to the loop, and since it's never used, the `for` loop isn't doing anything.

Comment: Shouldn't `"object"` in `"GetCustomobjectDataForStandardObject"` be `"Object"`? Not sure, just was reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark based on your sample code, since I don't know anything about dapper (I'm assuming this is dapper? If so, please add the `Dapper` tag to your question), but see if something like this gets you closer to what you want.

I'm using `ToList()` on the call to `QueryAsync`, so for each `result` in `mapResult`, a new `List<rowData>` is returned. Then calling `.ToList()` on the `.Select` statement returns the result as a `List<List<rowData>>`, where each inner list is a row of values, and the outer list is a list of rows.

The code below would replace your `for` loop:

```
var rowsAffected = mapResult.Select(result =>
    {
        DynamicParameters pa = new DynamicParameters();
        pa.Add("@CustomObjectSchemaId", result.CustomObjectID);
        return await con.QueryAsync(StoredProcedure.GetCustomObjectData, 
            pa, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
    }).ToList();

// rowsAffected is a List<List<rowData>>, where the outer list contains all the rows
// and each inner list is the row data for a specific row
```

Comment: Dapper is using in my namespace reference.dapper used for dynamicparameters.mapresult have all IDs so i declared the loop for mapresult and passed customobjectid one by one to my procedure and get the data and stored in rowaffected var.so i  need to read var values and stored data in a list unless loop stoped.

Comment: Ok. Does this sample work for you? I can't tell from your comment.  Adding a `dapper` tag to your question will bring in more dapper experts.